# Ruby: 4-bytes array to int32

Tags: ruby, arrays, type-conversion, tcpsocket, int32

There are 4 bytes read from `TCPSocket` (actually socket returns a string and then I call `.bytes` to get an array). Now they need to be converted to int32 big endian.

Or may be TCPSocket has some method to read int32 immediately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-pack). The argument indicates the type of conversion. `"N"` is used below and denotes "32-bit unsigned, network (big-endian) byte order". See the link for all options.

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x01".unpack("N")
# => [1]

"\x00\x00\x00\xFF".unpack("N")
# => [255]
```

Note the result is an `Array`, so apply `[0]` or `.first` to obtain the `Fixnum`.

---

*Original answer with Array#pack with transforms byte Array to binary String:*

You can use [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-pack)

```
# unsigned 32-bit integer (big endian)
bytes.pack('L>*')

# signed 32-bit integer (big endian)
bytes.pack('l>*')
```

Maybe you will find the `N` directive useful, which stands for "Network byte order"

```
# 32-bit unsigned, network (big-endian) byte order
bytes.pack('N*')
```

Comment: Since he starts with a String from TCPSocket, would [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-unpack) not be slightly more suitable? For example `"\x00\x00\x00\xFF".unpack("N*")"` => `[255]`. Array#pack also seems to still yield a binary string not a number?

Comment: @p11y: shouldn't it be str.unpack instead of str.pack ?

Comment: @Paul Yes you probably want to use that, see my comment earlier.

Comment: @Daniël Knippers: I just do not understand the answer completely. There is a reference to `unpack` at the beginning, but all the examples use `pack` which produces a string rather than integer. I am a bit cautious to edit answer by myself as I could miss some hidden sense in there.

Comment: @Paul I edited the answer to include working examples for `String#unpack`, I put his old answer below it for reference which transforms an Array of bytes into a binary String.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers thanks for the edit and sorry for the confusion. I am on my mobile device right now and simply messed up the edit.